# Complex regex in ruby

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, regex

I have a complex regex to make in ruby.

```
str = '1:2-2:1015-3:1007,=,0-4:2,|,3'
regex = /(\d+):|(\d+),\|,(\d+)/
```

My goal is to find only certain digits (those before ':' for example) and add a number to all of them.

Example: if I want to add 20 to all of them, my str would look like this :

```
str = '21:2-22:1015-23:1007,=,0-24:22,|,23'
```

I can find them with this regex, but I can't find how to make an addition.

I tried a few things like this :

```
str.gsub(/(\d+):/){|m| m.to_i + 30}
Result : "312-321015-331007,=,0-3432"
```

It deleted the ':', the '|', and didn't make the addition for the last digit.

I'm sure I'm doing it wrong. Perhaps with map, and scan I could do something right?

Thanks for your help, I hope my explanations are clear.

Edit : The two solution bellow are correct for me, do not hesitate to read both of them

Comment: Please do not forget to accept the solution that works best for you. Note that you can upvote any solution that you find helpful.

Comment: I'll not forget, I'm trying for now, two solutions are ok for me :)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

There is a lot easier way:

```
▶ str = '1:2-2:1015-3:1007,=,0-4:2,|,3'
▶ regex = /\d+(?=:)|\d+(?=,\|,\d)|(?<=\d,\|,)\d+/
▶ str.gsub(regex) { |m| (m.to_i + 20).to_s }
#⇒ "21:2-22:1015-23:1007,=,0-24:22,|,23"
```

The trick here is that we match *digits only* to make them easy to subst. Positive lookaheads help to catch those digits (note, that there are now 3 different conditions, to always match the single number.)

Comment: If you are using zero-width assertions, you do not need capturing groups. You may just use `/\d+(?=:)|\d+(?=,\|,\d)|(?<=\d,\|,)\d+/`

Comment: please tell me what is a zero-width assertions ?

Comment: Those  are anchors (`^`, `\A`, `$`, `\z`, etc.), word boundaries (`\b`, `\B`) and [lookarounds](http://www.regular-expressions.info/lookaround.html) like `(?!\d)` (lookahead) and `(?<=\d)` (lookbehind).

Comment: @WiktorStribiżew indeed, thanks, this is a matter of copy-paste.

Answer (score 2):

Your last regex does not match the `(\d+),\|,(\d+)` pattern you had in the original pattern. Note that since you already match `:` and `,|,`, you need to reinsert them in the replacement. Also, what is more important, you only need to apply addition to the *captured* values, not the whole matched text.

Use something like

```
str = '1:2-2:1015-3:1007,=,0-4:2,|,3'
regex = /(\d+):|(\d+),\|,(\d+)/
toadd  = 20
puts str.gsub(regex) { $~[2] ? "#{$~[2].to_i + toadd},|,#{$~[3].to_i + toadd}" : "#{$~[1].to_i + toadd}:" }
```

See the [online demo](https://ideone.com/bDtVTM)

You need to check if Group 2 (`$~[2]`) matched first, and if yes, only perform addition to groups 2 and 3, and if not, only add to Group 1 (`$~[1]`) contents.

Comment: This is so perfect, I need to pratice more regex i guess.
Really a lot of thanks.

Comment: Positive lookaheads provide the ability to use block version of gsub to perform the requested operation.

Comment: I'm trying to understand how this really works, maybe later I'll need to add an other option like (\d+),\&,(\d+).
With your solution I'll need to make an other inner condition (don't know this a correct sentence sorry) ?

Comment: No, you will need an alterantion or a character class in the pattern. Here, I'd use  a character class `[|&]`: `/(\d+):|(\d+),[|&],(\d+)/`. The point is that you cannot always rely on a lookbehind as it cannot be of infinite width in Ruby regex. Lookarounds are also costlier in terms of performance.

Comment: Didn't thought about this, i like your way but it's more complicated for my use, but i learned something very useful anyway :D
Thanks again !

Comment: What do you mean by infinite width ? if the str is too long for regex ?

Comment: Good, but remember that once you have an unknown number of chars in between the two numbers, the lookbehind solution will stop working. Like `2,,,,,|,,3` or `4,,,|,,,,5` to be converted to `22,,,,,|,,23` or `24,,,|,,,,25`. What I mean is you cannot use `(?<=\d,+\|,+)\d+` in a Ruby regex.

Comment: That's all clear ! I do not have this kind of case on my work but i'll remember of course :)
You were really helpful, making my day !

Comment: Please, tell me if I'm wrong, I practising myself with your regex, I wanted to add a third possibilities with `\d,!`
I did this :
`regex = /(\d+):|(\d+),!|(\d+),[|&],(\d+)/` and 
`puts str.gsub(regex) { $~[3] ? "#{$~[3].to_i + numberToAdd},|,#{$~[4].to_i + numberToAdd}" : $~[1] ? "#{$~[1].to_i + numberToAdd}:" : "#{$~[2].to_i + numberToAdd},!"  }`
The result is ok for me, but I'm not sure if i'm doing this right

Comment: You are complicating things, use `regex = /(\d+)(:|,!)|(\d+),[|&],(\d+)/` and then [`str.gsub(regex) { $~[3] ? "#{$~[3].to_i + toadd},|,#{$~[4].to_i + toadd}" : "#{$~[1].to_i + toadd}#{$~[2]}" }`](https://ideone.com/AUtig2). Mudasobwa's (Alexei's) regex: `/\d+(?=:|,!)|\d+(?=,[|&],\d)|(?<=\d,[|&],)\d+/`